# How to deal with Choreographer: Skipped 130 frames when I got ListView inside BaseAdapter

Tags: android, performance, android-listview

I have a fragment called `NoteList` that showing list of data from json. Inside my main ListView, I loaded it with another ListView. I use `BaseAdapter`. So that, inside that adapter, I execute another `BaseAdapter` to fill in the inner ListView. Everything went well.

But I am not satisfied when every time opening the LogCat. I got to see this `I/Choreographer: Skipped 130 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.`

The JSON data doesn't containing any image, only Strings.

How to deal with this?

Answer (score 0):

The error itself is self explanatory `The application may be doing too much work on its main thread`. So, move some code out from main thread to a background thread. Check if you are parsing data on the main thread. Even if there are no images, all HTTP connections and parsing of JSON data must be done on background thread